# Does pig support load with no delimiter?

Tags: apache-pig

I'd like to load a lot of small files from HDFS with Pig and process them as tuples (filename, filecontent).

```
a=LOAD 'mydir' USING PigStorage('','-tagPath') AS (filepath:chararray, filecontents:chararray);
```

However it seems like I cannot omit specifying the delimiter. Is there some sort of a "NULL" in Pig or is there any other way to make sure the content of the file will not be split?

Comment: can you share sample input for ref ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own custom loader by extending `LoadFunc`.

Short answer to your question is no.In order to make sure the content is not split,use a delimiter that would not exist in the content.In that way, the whole content would be loaded to the field `filecontents:chararray`.So assuming,your input files do not have a special character '~'

```
a=LOAD 'mydir' USING PigStorage('~','-tagPath') AS (filepath:chararray, filecontents:chararray);
```